# Simple basis for Barnes-Wall lattices in dimension `$2^n$`

Tags: nt.number-theory, ag.algebraic-geometry

I'm searching for a "simple" description of the basis of the Barnes-Wall lattices 
in (real) dimension $2^n$, if possible in a basis of minimal vectors, so that I can 
do some calculations.

Can anyone tell me where to find such a description ?

**Note :** I'm not looking for examples in fixed dimensions, like the D4, or E8 
lattices. I know where to look up those. I'm looking for a formula / systematic
description in all dimensions of powers of 2.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Henry Cohn cited a very nice definition of the Barnes-Wall lattices, but in my opinion, [this definition](http://www.cs.stevens.edu/~nicolosi/papers/isit08.pdf) that I just found in a paper by Micciancio and Nicoli is even better.  (Although the two definitions are similar.)  The Barnes-Wall lattice in $\mathbb{C}^{2^{n-1}}$ is a lattice over the Gaussian integers generated by the rows of the matrix
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 1+i \end{pmatrix}^{\otimes {n-1}}.$$
Then of course to get the generator matrix in $\mathbb{R}^{2^n}$, you use the replacement
$$a+ib \mapsto \begin{pmatrix} a & b \\ -b & a \end{pmatrix}.$$
This isn't a basis of minimal vectors.  However, if you change the Gaussian generator matrix to
$$\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 \\ 1 & i \end{pmatrix}^{\otimes {n-1}},$$
then it is a basis of minimal vectors, and the associated real basis is also minimal.

Comment: This is great! I had no idea one could make it even simpler than the Nebe-Rains-Sloane definition.

Answer (score 6):

Nebe, Rains, and Sloane have a beautiful paper called "A simple construction for the Barnes-Wall lattices" (http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0207186).  Their construction is great: consider two vectors of norm $2$ with inner product $\sqrt{2}$, and let $L$ be the $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{2}]$ lattice they span.  Then up to scaling, the Barnes-Wall lattice of dimension $2^n$ is the sublattice of the $n$-th tensor power $L^{\otimes n}$ fixed by conjugation (i.e., fixed under interchanging $\sqrt{2}$ and $-\sqrt{2}$).

Slightly more explicitly, take $(\sqrt{2},0)$ and $(1,1)$ as a basis of $L$, and then the Barnes-Wall lattice is the intersection of $L^{\otimes n}$ with $\mathbb{Q}^{2^n}$.

Answer (score 1):

All I can give you is some names and sites. Gabriele Nebe co-owns the Lattices site with Sloane, http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/  and http://www.math.rwth-aachen.de/~Gabriele.Nebe/LATTICES/  and has some work of her own on high-dimensional lattices. She gave a very positive review of a book by Jacques Martinet, *Perfect Lattices in Euclidean Spaces.* Finally, you might look through every publication by Daniel Allcock, he was the most helpful to me on my final covering radius question, http://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/allcock/